# Draggable / Sortable helper size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im wondering if anyone can help me with this jquery draggable sortable problem? I have some dragabbles that are connected to some sortable lists.  When the draggable helper is over a sortable and the sortable placeholder is visiable I would like the draggable helper change width (animate ideally) to be the correct width of the sortable area. Now the height can just stay the same I just want the draggable helper width to match the sortable placeholder width.

JSBin file example (http://jsbin.com/oHeGexa/5/edit).  So lets say I drag the green square which is 40px width and height when picked up.  When it is moved over the first sortable area (which is 150px) the green square goes to 150px wide.  When its moved over the 2nd sortable area it is resized again to 250px which is thats sortables size and keeps changing size when moved over the areas.

I cant seem to work this out because I dont know how to access the draggable helper from within the sortable over method.

I cant find the answer on Google either.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: you want to change the width when it is hovered over sortable or when it is dropped?

Comment: when is is hovered.  I know how to get to he dropped item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
$(".dragMe").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair",
    connectToSortable: ".sortMe",
    helper: "clone"
});

$(".sortMe").sortable({
    connectWith: "",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    over: function(e, ui){ 
        ui.helper.width(ui.sender.width()-10); 
        ui.item.width(ui.sender.width()-10);
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oHeGexa/7/edit

You'll notice that once a draggable enters

---

I had to make some modifications to your initial code to get it to work because.

When `connectWith:".sortMe"` is set the `over` function does not trigger when initially hovering over sortables.  Only after one square is dropped in a sortable then the `over` function gets called.  Further complicating things is that the `UI` object is different depending on whether `over` is called from the `draggables` or `sortables`.

When dragging from the sortables the `ui.sender.width()` does not change when hovering over different sortable's.

Anyway here is a start.  Needless to say if you want it to work so that you can drag blocks to other sortables and have it re-size once the block is already in a sort-able area that is going to take more work.  I'll look into it a little more but it hasn't been easy to figure out.

Comment: before I even try this with my real code I just wanna say thank you  =) I love your demos and I can clearly see how you've done it.  Your code also might have helped me with something else im doing inadvertedly.  I'll let you know how I get on soon, thanks again.

Comment: @SubstanceD your welcome, please mark this answer as accepted if it helped answer your question.  Thanks

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.  Ive tried practically all day to make it work bug free but its been very tricky and still isnt quite right.  Your answer is defnitely good though am accepting as the best solution.  Thanks again for you help  =)